# Find $V_\lambda$ of Given vector space and derivative operator $T: V \rightarrow V$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lambda-calculus

Given $V = Fn(x)$ a vector space. With derivative operator $T: V \rightarrow V$, $T(p(x)) = p'(x)$

I proved that $V$ is a vector space by showing that all the axioms are true, and after that, I found the only eigenvalue of $T$ which is $\lambda = 0$, now I'm asked to find the Vector space of $\lambda$ which is $V_\lambda$, any idea or a hint for how to find it?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Comment: Is $F_{n}$ supposed to be the space of polynomials with degree less than equal to $n$? . If so then what is $F$ ? What is it's characteristic?

Comment: it's a polynom where $a_n\neq0$ I think.

Comment: @BlackHat It can't have that condition ($a_n\ne 0$) since that doesn't give a vector space.

Comment: @BlackHat  " I'm asked to find the Vector space of λ which is $V_λ$ " . What do you mean by a " vector space of $\lambda$ "?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the kernel of the derivative operator $T$.

If $Fn(x)$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients in a field $k$ of degree $n$ (with $a_n\ne0$ ad $a_i=0$ for each $i>n$) and the constant $0$, there is a problem with the definition of $T$ (because if you derive a degree $n$ polynomial, you get a degree $\leqslant n-1$ polynomial.

So let me assume that $Fn(x)$ is the set of polynomial with degree $\leqslant n$. Then a polynomial is of the form
$$
p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i.
$$
And
$$
p'(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (i+1)a_{i+1} x^{i}.
$$
So the kernel is the set of polynomials s.t.
$$
(i)a_{i}=0\quad \text{for each }i\in\{ 1,\cdots, n\}.
$$
If the characteristic of the field $k$ is $0$ you get that the kernel is done by the constant polynomial, so
$$
V_0=k.
$$
If the characteristic of the field $k$ is $p$ you get that the kernel is done by polynomial of the form
$$
\sum_{i=0}^s a_{ip} x^{ip}\quad \text{s.t. }sp\leqslant n\text{ and } a_{ip}\in k.
$$
So
$$
V_0=\bigoplus_{s=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\rfloor} \{a_{sp} x^{sp}\mid a_{sp}\in k\}=\bigoplus_{s=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\rfloor} k<x^{sp}>.
$$
(where $k<x^{sp}>$ means the $k$-vector space generated by $x^{sp}$).

I hope that my definition is equal to your definition.